# How does not use the loop output 99 multiplication table？

Tags: java

I want to output 99 multiplication table not use the loop. Do not say only use 'system.out.print'.

Comment: You can use `System.out.println()` as well, if you like.

Comment: A loop is a means for performing an incremental logic for an algorithm (such as producing a multiplication table). System.out.print is a function for printing data to the output. Perhaps you mean to say - 'suggest a solution, other than hard coded printing of the results'. Anyway, you haven't demonstrated any code or real effort in your question. Voting to close.

Comment: You will either need to provide all the input ("use only print"). Or you'll need to apply some form of algorithm. In this case, such an algorithm probably needs to "loop" in some fashion, but there are different ways it can be done. Consider these: `for/while`, iterate-over-a-collection, or recursion (the posted answer shows a form of co-recursion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class NextDiGui {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                row();
        }
        static int num1 =0,  num2 =1;
        public static void row(){
                num1++;

                if(num1<10){
                        col();
                }
        }
        public static void col(){

                if(num2<=num1){

                        System.out.print(num1+"*"+num2+"="+num1*num2+"\t");
                        num2++;
                        col();
                }
                else{
                        num2=1;
                        System.out.println();
                        row();

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: The most interesting use of recursive I've seen in awhile.. *shrug*